# How to use script tag in an ASP.NET Core MVC razor view

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core

I want to use javascript in a razor view in the MVC project. I want to show a message to the user by clicking the post button. I put the script tag in `Section` below the page but on hitting F12 it shows `'btn' is null`. I'm testing my project on IISExpress in Firefox

```
<form method="post">
--------a few input fields in a form-------
 <button id="button" type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">send</button>
</form>
<div class="submit-progress d-none">
    <label>be patient please...</label>
</div>
@section scripts{
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-fileinput/5.2.7/js/fileinput.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            const btn = document.getElementById("#button");
            btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
                $(btn).prop("disabled", true);
                $(".submit-progress").removeClass("d-none");
            })
        });
    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple problems with your code mostly from mixing jQuery and native JavaScript methods.  You can make it work by fixing the 3 lines shown to use jQuery. Note that "this" refers to the element to which the event handler is attached, in this case the button.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // const btn = document.getElementById("#button"); <-- REMOVE
  $("#button").click(function() { // <-- CHANGE
    $(this).prop("disabled", true); // <-- CHANGE
    $(".submit-progress").removeClass("d-none");
  })
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Man! Could you please help me with another issue? In my form, I have a client-side validation which means If you hit send button without filling the form, validation tag errors appear without sending to the server. The problem is with appearing .submit-progress div. I want it to appear only when the user fills the form and hits the send button

Answer (score 2):

When using getElementById you only need to pass the name not the selector #

```
const btn = document.getElementById("button");
```

You have used the scripts section correctly.

Comment: up voted as this is the most simple answer, though I think OP also needs to understand that they are mixing jQuery and native js in a confusing code salad.